# Как ускорить данный скрипт для Perfect Click?

Tags: java

1. Определение точек на экране:

`stickT` и `stickB` представляют верхний левый и нижний правый углы некоторой наклейки соответственно.
`updBtn, buyBtn` и `confirmBtn` - координаты кнопок "Обновить", "Купить" и "Подтвердить" соответственно.
Переменные:

`slotH` представляет собой высоту слота.
`slotCount` указывает на количество слотов для проверки (в данном случае, 3).

2. Запуск захвата экрана и пауза:

`startScreenCapture(2)` запускает захват экрана з минимально возможным временем отклика автокликера, на происходящее на экране.
`sleep(5)` делает паузу в 5 миллисекунд.
Основной цикл:

3. В бесконечном цикле `(while(!EXIT))`, скрипт выполняет следующие действия:
   Использует вложенный цикл для проверки каждого слота на экране.
   Если количество контуров в текущем слоте больше 2, то выполняются действия: нажатие на кнопку "Купить" в текущем слоте и затем нажатие на кнопку "Подтвердить". Затем цикл прерывается `(break)`.
   Если прошло более 6 секунд с последнего обновления, то происходит нажатие на кнопку "Обновить" дважды. После этого обновляется время `(time = Time.getMillis())`.
   После каждой итерации основного цикла происходит пауза в 30 миллисекунд.

```
//Верхний левый угол наклейки
Point stickT = Point.get(1219,433);
//Нижний правый угол наклейки
Point stickB = Point.get(1261,502);

//Координаты кнопки [Обновить]
Point updBtn = Point.get(712,370);

//Координаты кнопки [Купить]
Point buyBtn = Point.get(1712,465);

//Координаты кнопки [Подтвердить]
Point confirmBtn = Point.get(951,715);

//Высота слота
int slotH = 114;

//Количество слотов для проверки
int slotCount = 3;


startScreenCapture(2);
sleep(5);

long time = Time.getMillis(); 

Point tempTop = Point.get();
tempTop.x = stickT.x;

Point tempBot = Point.get();
tempBot.x = stickB.x;

while(!EXIT)
{ 
     

     for(int i = 0; i < slotCount ; i++)
     {
     tempTop.y = stickT.y + (i * slotH);
     tempBot.y = stickB.y + (i * slotH);

     if(getContoursCount(tempTop, tempBot) > 2)
      {
       click(buyBtn.x, buyBtn.y + (i * slotH));
       sleep(19);
       click(confirmBtn);
       
      }
     }

  if((Time.getMillis() - time) > 6000){
    click(updBtn);
    sleep(100);
    click(updBtn);

    
    sleep(5);
       

    time = Time.getMillis(); 
  }

  sleep(30);
}
```

Comment: Добавьте описание работы кода.

Comment: @Глеб Написал (вроде как)

Answer (score 0):

добавить воид , использовать между нажатиями Thread.sleep(); , это используется для задержки в команде Thread.sleep(); можно ставить задежку 0 это лучше чем использовать слип с минимальной зд 5

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые и понятные другим ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]